# How to set dpi when renderInContext

Tags: ios, image, pdf, vector, dpi

I am creating an iPad app. I need generate a PDF report with a complicated layout. I have two options:

1. Using Apple's built-in API to create a `.pdf` with all the meta data. It will cost a lot of time.
2. Creating a `UIScrollView` and adding cell to it, then capturing the screen and saving as a PDF page.

I would prefer to use the second option, as it is quicker. However, the PDF size is very big, because I am capturing the screen to a PDF instead of making a vector file.

The pdf could be 50 MB, I cannot even email it out. The DPI is very high on retina iPad, it's 300. I was thinking if I can make it 72 DPI, the file size would be lower.

How could I achieve that?

Below is the code for capturing the screen and saving to a PDF:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH(self), offsetY), nil);
                    [scrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
                    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing the `contentsScale` of the `CALayer` in order to reduce the resolution of your content? See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/contentsScale